Installing Java
I am trying to install Java. but I am getting following Issue: -
I downloaded jdk-8u201-linux-i586.tar.gz from oracle web site.
Then I created directories as sudo mkdir /usr/local/java
After that i moved the downloaded file to dir
sudo mv jdk-8u201-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/local/java
I unpacked the same      sudo tar zxvf jdk-8u201-linux-i586.tar.gz
Then set the alternative link as
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java" 1
After that i tried java -version,
it is returning error as "bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory".
Kindly anyone help me in this matter,

try using this command in the terminal:
sudo apt install default-jre

then you can try using:
java -version

to check version

THANK YOU FOR YOUR SUPPORT

Hi, Sorry for the delayed reply. I have already tried the same. But it will install open JDK. I need to install Oracle Java with access  Java Control panel for adding urls in the security of the Java control panel. I need this to access the oracle EBS instance at my PC.

Do not download binaries straight from the Internet. That is not how to install software on Linux. It is how Windows users do it, but it is wrong on Linux.
Install it from the package manager. Google for instructions for your version, since you did not bother to tell us what you are running. Without detailed specific info we can't help you.

THANK YOU FOR FOR SUPPORT
